# Angular ngOnChanges doesn't fire when input field updates

Tags: angular

I'm trying to learn `ngOnChanges`.

The world's smallest Angular template-driven form:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="hero" name="hero">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Its TypeScript component class:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-form',
  templateUrl: './hero-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-form.component.css']
})
export class HeroFormComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() hero: string | null = null;

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.hero);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log("Changes!");
    console.log(this.hero);
    console.log(changes);
  }

}
```

And its module:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroFormComponent } from './hero-form/hero-form.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm not seeing any error messages.

When I enter a name in the field and click "Submit" I see the name in the log (from the `onSubmit()` handler) but nothing logs from `ngOnChanges()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think there might be a misunderstanding here. @Input decorator has nothing to do with a form <input>. It is used as a ‘component’ input in case a child components needs data from a parent component..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ngOnChanges** : Only triggers when there is change in @Input properties from parent to child. It doesn't care about child component changes

https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges